# Merge list into list of tuples of 4 items

Tags: python, list, tuples

here is the list that I want to merge

```
l = [3.23, 5.32, 8.23, 2.23, 9.98, 7.43, 6.43, 8.23, 4.23]
```

the list has to be sorted from high to low

```
l.sort()
l.reverse
```

I need this as a result

```
p = [(9.98, 8.23, 8.23, 7.43), (6.43, 5.32, 4.23, 3.23), (2.23,)]
```

Can someone help me do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

First sort the list in descendant order:

```
l=sorted(l,reverse=True)
```

Then use list comprehension to merge the list into tuples of 4 items:

```
[tuple(l[i:i + 4]) for i in range(0, len(l), 4)]
```